# Plot graph in a pdf file python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pdf, networkx

I have some networkx graph and I would print it in a pdf file with a loop, but each time I do a plot, it's already the same graph, only the first which is print.

```py
pdf=fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial",size=12)
pdf.write(5,'First sentence\n')

#Print with a loop :
for i in range(0,len(Sub_graph)):

  pdf.write(5,"\n Graph " + str(i+1) + ":\n")

  #plt.show()
  position = nx.spring_layout(Sub_graph[i])
  nx.draw(Sub_graph[i], position)                  
  node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(Sub_graph[i],'name')
  nx.draw_networkx_labels(Sub_graph[i], position, labels = node_labels)
  edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(Sub_graph[i],'correlation')
  nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(Sub_graph[i], position, edge_labels)

  #I tried with a tmp save
  plt.savefig('tmp.jpg')             
  pdf.image('tmp.jpg')
  plt.show()
  plt.close()
  os.remove('tmp.jpg')

  pdf.write(5,"write something in the file")
```

My pdf results is :

text
Graph 1
text
Graph 1
text
Graph 1

I always have the Graph 1 which is printed in the pdf, how could I make the good graph appear ?

(When I do plt.show() it show me the good Graph)

Comment: Do you maybe mean to add a new page each iteration through the loop?

Comment: No, fpdf creates pages automatically : I can put/write text and the graphics at the end of  the pdf file, in the following, int the order of the loop. But it's always the first pictures/graph which is print, so there is a mistake somewhere in my code, or something that I don't understand with plt.close() or pdf.image() because when I use plt.show() it is the right graph which is showed (but I would print it in the pdf not in my jupyter cell)